# Setting widths of elements in percentages for responsiveness

Tags: html, css

If I set the container (`div`) containing four items to `100%` and make the elements (`li`) `25%` with no margins or paddings on any of the elements, shouldn't each of the elements fit perfectly on one line in the container? Why does it not and why does the last one run onto the next line?

HTML ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/somj9pq2/))

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><img src="http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/2/29462/582674-kenny.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/2/29462/582674-kenny.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/2/29462/582674-kenny.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/2/29462/582674-kenny.png" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
}

div {
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    width: 25%;
}

img {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/arshadmuhammed/n4e1ncvh/1/

Add `float:left` to your li

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    width: 25%;
    float:left;
}
```

**ANSWER to your second question:**
2) Instead of giving margin, give border & box-sizing to your li inorder to get even spacing between them.

```
li {
    box-sizing:border-box;/*new*/
    list-style: none;
    width: 25%;
    float:left;
    background:red;
    border:20px solid white;/*new*/
}
```

Comment: Thank you for both answers! I edited my question to only ask the first one because I thought I was asking for too much in one question. But thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As you told, When you set he width is 100% and image width is 25% then why the last image goes to next line because you haven't define the position of you image.. Add `float:left;` in your code..

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because of whitespaces between inline-blocks in your HTML. Remove them :

`<div>
    <ul>
        <li><img src="http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/2/29462/582674-kenny.png" /></li><!--
        --><li><img src="http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/2/29462/582674-kenny.png" /></li><!--
        --><li><img src="http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/2/29462/582674-kenny.png" /></li><!--
        --><li><img src="http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/2/29462/582674-kenny.png" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>`

Updated JSfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/somj9pq2/4/